# How to say "This photo was considered as evidence that she was not raped"?

Tags: traducción

How would one say "This photo was considered as evidence that she was not raped"?

I have translated it as "Esto foto se consideraron pruebas admisible de que ella no fue violada" but this doesn't sound right.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero supongo que podría ser: "Esta foto se consideraba evidencia de que (ella) no fue violada". ¿Cuál es el contexto?

Comment: "This photo" is singular and feminine in Spanish so it should be "Esta foto fue considerada". In Spanish it exists the word "evidencia" whose meaning match "prueba determinante en un proceso (judicial)" so you can simplify "Esta foto fue considerada evidencia de que no fue violada". There is no need in Spanish to include the pronoun "ella" but it depends on the context.

Comment: @RubioRic that comment looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks but I think that the question should be closed. This is not a free translation site. OP should show some effort and specify what is his problem with the text, in my opinion

Comment: the OP show some effort providing a translation of their own, but it's true that it's unclear what they don't understand besides "it sounds weird". I think the OP's level of proficiency maybe is good enough to realize something is odd not not good enough to figure out what by themselves. This questions is kind of in a grey area off-topic wise to me.

Comment: For those that voted to close it... I would think that there is some effort and the OP translated the sentence by himself/herself since using Google translate would give a good result. However using google translate would not teach him/her as much as we can here. So, see my answer below. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The translation has a few mistakes that I will try to explain here.

First *"This photo"* is singular because it is not "these photos". Also "photo" *(foto/fotografía)* is feminine in Spanish so you should use "esta" instead of "este/esto" then this segment translates to "Esta foto".

"Se consideraron" is plural and again our sentence is about a single photo so "was considered" can be translated to "se consideró" or better yet "fue considerada"

"prueba admisible" is ok but also the word "evidencia" is a valid alternative.

The final sentence would then be:

> "Esta foto fue considerada evidencia de que (ella) no fue violada".
>
> "Esta foto se consideró evidencia de que (ella) no fue violada".

There is no need in Spanish to include the pronoun "ella" but including it is also ok

Answer (score 1):

Esta foto(grafía) se consideró prueba evidencial de que no fue violada.

ver la diferencia entre *evidencia* y *prueba (evidencial)* en http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/evidentemente-evidencia-no-es-lo-mismo-que-prueba/

Comment: Bienvenida al stack. gracias por la aportación. Tu contribución ganaría mucho si añadieses aquí el contenido relevante del enlace. Así, primero su la página enlazada desaparece tu respuesta aquí no pierde contenido y segundo, en lugar de decirle a otra persona que se vaya a buscar la respuesta a otro sitio, se lea el artículo y lo entienda, pues le explicas las partes más relevantes. Gracias.

Comment: Aun siendo corta, esta respuesta es la única que indica correctamente que la traducción del inglés "evidence" es "prueba", y no "evidencia". Dada la falta de contexto en la pregunta, esta es la única respuesta que me parece correcta.